# Limiting Distributions and Weak Law of Large Numbers

Tags: inference, law-of-large-numbers

I have that $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ are i.i.d. Poisson random variables with mean 1, and that $U_n = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{Y_i^2}}{n}}$.

Given that I have a sequence $U_1, U_2, ..., U_n$, I'm trying to find the pdf/pmf of the limiting distribution for $U$.

I believe that I can use the Weak Law of Large Numbers to handle $\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{Y_i^2}}{n}}$, since that expression is comparable to $\overline{Y^2}$ (if that's a thing). I believe that I would be trying to take the limit of the MGF of $U$ to see if there a limiting distribution.

I tried using various approaches, such as letting $g(y) = y^2$ and trying to solve for MGFs, but I'm getting stuck with my math. Any pointers?

Comment: Yes, indeed, $Y_1^2,\ldots$ are i.i.d integrable random variables, so actually the strong law applies and $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 \to \mathbb{E} Y_1^2 = 2$ almost surely.  Also $\sqrt{n}(U_n^2 - 2)$ converges to a Normal distribution with mean zero and variance that I cannot be bothered to compute.  Not sure if that helps for your application. I think it would be possible to get a more exact  answer but haven't tried.

Comment: So if it converges to $E(Y_1^2)=2$, does that mean that the limiting distribution for U is a degenerate at $sqrt(2)$?

Comment: Yes.  To get a non-degenerate limit you need "central limit theorem" type scaling.

Comment: Observe that the variance of $U_n^2$ is $n^{-1}$Var$(Y_1^2)$.